# Jquery function value changes unexpectedly with external variable change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I have a code that keeps updating a list of "cards", during setup it applies this code to add an edit button that fires a universal modal:

```
$("#C" + cardID + "Edit").off('click').click(function() {
    editCard(cardID);
});
```

Where cardID is in a loop that sets every card, and goes from 1 to 5 for my cards (`C1Edit`, `C2Edit`, etc). I am using `.off('click')` as currently the same code that keeps the values updated adds the events to the buttons in the cards.

The function `editCard()` is as follows:

```
function editCard(id) {
    selectedCard = id;
    $("#cardEditName").val($("#C" + id + "T").html());
    $("#cardEditUnit").val($("#C" + id + "U").html());
}
```

The issue is, when I click on the button `#C2Edit`, I get an id of 5. Which means that somehow the function is trying to access the current value of `cardID`, instead of taking the value when button was created.

I am not really sure how to resolve this issue, or if there is something obvious that I missed (which I expect to be the case).

**My loop:**

```
for (element in result) {
   cardID = element;
   .
   .
   $("#C" + cardID + "Edit").off('click').click(function() {
    editCard(cardID);
   });
}
```

I know that my loop should work fine, as other fields that are set (I am setting a number of fields at once) are appearing correctly as far as I can see.

Comment: SHOW YOUR LOOP. Has nothing to do with the editCard function. It has to do with the click function binding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: So why are you using a global variable? `cardID` is global. Whatevery is in the click() is going to read that global variable when it is clicked.

Comment: @epascarello which global variable? I am a bit confused here. Am I unintensionally using a global variable I shouldn't be using here?

Comment: `editCard(cardID);` <-- reads the global variable. It does not hold the state of `cardID` at that moment it time. So it gets the last value of the for loop.

Comment: I see, in that case, how do I store the current value for the function? Would an option like setting another variable to read the value of cardID work perhaps?

Comment: Why is cardID global? Shove `var` or `const` in front of it.

Comment: It isn't supposed to be global, but I guess it is a result of me not using let cardID; here?

Comment: WHY is it global, it makes no sense. It will always be the last value in the loop.

Comment: I use it in other locations in the loop, that's why its in the above context

Comment: It is in the loop then it should still be declared with const or var. Global is for when you need access it to things outside the scope of the function.

Comment: Using `var` didn't fix it, but using `let` and `const` did, do post that as an answer if you don't mind so I can accept it. Thanks for your help. I do have some things related to JS that I misunderstand. Apologies for the bother.

Comment: To clairfy: `x = 1` without var/let/const auto-magically makes `x` a global variable no matter where `x=1` runs (assuming it hasn't been defined previously, of course).  There's subtle differences between `var` and `let` but they don't work exactly like `var` in other languages such as c#.  There's better places to explain the differences in more detail.

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m for the clarification, that makes sense. I will read up a bit more on that.